# Como limitar para não poder passar de 3 unidades de um livro em uma locadora PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, pl-sql, apex

Estou fazendo uma livraria em APEX e não posso permitir que o cliente alugue mais de 3 livros. Porém mesmo colocando o código o programa não barra.

```
declare
W_QUANTIDADE_EMPRESTIMOS number;
W_STATUS     LIVROS.IND_STATUS%TYPE;

begin

SELECT COUNT(EL.COD_EMPRESTIMO), L.IND_STATUS
into W_QUANTIDADE_EMPRESTIMOS, W_STATUS
FROM EMPRESTIMO_LIVRO EL
    ,LIVROS L
WHERE NM_USUARIO_LOC = :P16_NM_USUARIO_LOC;


IF W_QUANTIDADE_EMPRESTIMOS > 3 AND W_STATUS = 'P' THEN
 raise_application_error( -20001, 'Você já possui muitos livros alugados!');
end if;
 
end;
```

Comment: Johnny, você já verificou o que a sua query está colocando nas variáveis? Que condição a mais é esta W_STATUS?

Comment: O bloco roda ? Parece faltar um "group by" na sql.